# How to pivot data frame for one column

Tags: python, pandas

I tried with df.pivot and df.pivot_table but receive either an error or not the desired output.

I have the following dataframe:

```
Country         Status   Value    
Angola          0       6
Angola          1       13
Angola          0       10
Angola          1       11
Greece          1       3
Greece          0       2
Greece          1       7
Greece          0       3
```

Desired output (column 'Status'):

```
Country         0       1  
Angola          6       NaN
Angola          NaN     13
Angola          10      NaN
Angola          NaN     11
Greece          NaN     3
Greece          2       NaN
Greece          7       7
Greece          3       NaN
```

Comment: can you explain the logic?

Comment: `df.set_index(['Country', df.groupby('Country').cumcount(), 'Status']).Value.unstack().reset_index('Country').reset_index(drop=True).rename_axis(None, axis=1)`

Comment: @Manakin Basically, I want the category 'Status'  to be in separate columns.

Comment: @piRSquared I received the following error: Length mismatch: Expected 264 rows, received array of length 12

Comment: Hmm, weird.  I'd need to see the data that produced that error.